Should Portable Types Be Used in the Declaration of a Main Function? (C11)
This question came to me last night, and I couldn't find a definitive answer in my brief surf of Google. Should (or could) I use portable types (i.e int32_t) in the declaration of my program's main function? Example:
// Normal main function, works perfectly fine.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}

// Portable(?) main function.
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}

The portable main function compiles (GCC 14.1.1), but is it good practice?

That definition is non standard conforming, so I would say definitely avoid it, especially since it does not have any advantage over the standard int main(int, char**) prototype.

Why do you want to do that? Will the local int type not allow enough? The C Standard defines int argc. That int is portable, but you may get a conflict if int32_t isn't the same size as int. You've made your code non-portable.

@WeatherVane No, I am simply curious if it's possible; I was under the impression one should use portable types for as much as physically possible.

@MarcoBonelli Thank you for the speedy answer. Post it as an actual one and I'll accept it :)

The exact-size integer types from stdint.h are optional, and, therefore, from some perspectives they are less portable than the primitive int etc.

hehehe ... int32_t main(int32_t argc, /*u8*/char **argv) ... UTF-8 everywhere

You forgot the caller site, it is built with the standard data types. And commonly you cannot change this.

"I was under the impression one should use portable types for as much as physically possible" - I think the advice would be to always use those portable types when the bitwidth of the variable matters, which would include cases where the expected range is outside of a 16-bit value. Naturally when using standard libc functions, you should match the expected inputs/outputs of those functions, which (for example) often return "int".

@StreveFord Valuable advice, thank you!

The definition you provide is non-standard. Or better, it is defined by the standard to be "implementation defined" and therefore only allowed if your compiler (implementing the standard) allows such definition.
I am not aware of major compilers allowing an int32_t return value for main(). However, it must be noted that on various platforms int32_t is just a typedef for int. The standard does allow "equivalent" main() declarations where int is replaced by a type that is indirectly typedef'd from int, however this definitely varies depending on the platform.
Overall, this is not a portable definition. It may be allowed by the standard but there almost certainly are platforms where this is non-standard conforming. I would avoid it.

References from C99 standard N1256:

5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
int main(void) { /* ... */ }

or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }

or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.


[...]
9) Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as char ** argv, and so on.


An example of where using int32_t would be counter-productive is a system where int is a 16-bit type.  They're relatively rare these days (but still allowed by the standard), but in times past were very common.

Plus, there can be conforming implementations that don't even have an int32_t.  For example, because all integer types are 64 bits.
